# How to set ylim of pyplot manually rather than allowing it to scale automatially?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, data-analysis

I want to have my y-axis like this[image]

But, if I do `plt.ylim(0.001, 1000)`, it scales it like this
[image]

How can I get it fixed?

Comment: Did you plot your data using plt.semilogy?

Comment: Use [`plt.gca().set_aspect('auto')`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html) to remove the fixed aspect ratio set elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `semilogy(x, y)`, and then set your `y-limit` as you have shown.

Comment: Hi @Gorupria, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hi @David, Just did it. Sorry.